# 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')' when running `interaction.client.commands.get()` function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When running my code, there is no error but an error occurs when I run any command. I am also following the code and instructions [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#loading-command-files) as I am only learning discord.js.

This is the event for the 'interactionCreate' and a 'main' function to just start the bot in my main.js file:

````
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {return}

    const command = client.application.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    console.log(interaction.client.application.commands.cache)

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`)
        return
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        let error_msg = '```' + error + '```'

        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: `Error\n${error_msg}`, ephemeral: true })
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: `Error\n${error_msg}`, ephemeral: true })
        }
    }
})

client.commands = new Collection()

const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands')
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath)

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder)
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file)
        const command = require(filePath)

        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command)
        } else {
            console.warn(`${filePath} is missing 'data' or 'execute' property`)
        }
    }
}

try {
    client.login(TOKEN)
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
````

And this is one of my files for a command which is in a 'commands/math' folder

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('remainder')
        .setDescription('Find the remainder of two numbers when divided')
        .addIntegerOption((option) => option
            .setName('number1')
            .setDescription('Dividend')
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addIntegerOption((option) => option
            .setName('number2')
            .setDescription('Divisor')
            .setRequired(true)
        ),

    async execute(interaction) {
        let num1 = interaction.options.data[0].value
        let num2 = interaction.options.data[1].value

        await interaction.reply((num1 % num2).toString())
    }
}
```

This is the error that occurs when I run the remainder command, or any command.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

I found that the error was in the main.js file in the interactionCreate event on this line: `const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)`, but I was unable to find any alternatives to the 'get' function

I couldn't find much on google or anywhere, and I am quite new to programming in JavaScript, most of my experience is in other languages.

I am fairly certain the 'command' variable is supposed to contain the command that the interaction used, so I tried to find ways to get the command from the commandId or commandName but I couldn't find anything on google or stackoverflow.

Comment: You don't have to put codes in main function like C language and then call it, try doing it just like the discord.js guide and in order, hopefully the problem will solve itself :)

Comment: Oh yea, you're right. I put everything in a main function because the `rest.put()` function needed to be awaited so I put everything to an asynchronous function, but turns out it can function without being awaited.

Comment: Where do you define `client.commands`? Unsure if I'm missing it. The definition should be `client.commands = new Collection()`, `Collection` being an import from discord.js

Comment: I edited the code now, but before editing the code I just had an array called 'commands' that stored all the commands which then added the commands to the bot. I replaced it with `client.commands = new Collection()` and added the command there instead. But the error still hasn't gone though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the guide that you are using you cannot access `client.commands` through `interactions.client.commands` Have you tried replacing

```
const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)
```

in main.js to:

```
const command = interaction.client.application.commands.cache.get(interaction.commandName)
```

or to

```
const command = client.application.commands.get(interaction.commandName)
```

Comment: I tried the second one, and it threw the following error: `TypeError: client.application.commands.get is not a function`. The first one didn't throw any error, but it returned an undefined object because the `interaction.client.application.commands.cache` is empty. I also tried to replace having a 'commands' array to add the commands to the bot and replaced it with `client.commands = new Collection()` and `client.commands.set(command.data.name, command)` instead of pushing the command to the commands array. I also should probably update the code in this question then.

Comment: I actually found a way to fix it by using `const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)`, and now all the commands function